# Web Services and Queues

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Our Company has many Soap Services and a Few Web sites that just post XML to a page. I know that SOAP is just an envolpe that will allow you to wrap your XML into a definition so they can potential represent objects, but is there any difference in the way they are handled? Does IIS Create a queue(MSMQ) to handle Web Service requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MSMQ is not involved at all in a web service running in IIS.

If you want queueing, you will have to implement it yourself (maybe with queueing in MSMQ on the server or using a database).

Answer (score 0):

You can host an MSMQ bound service in IIS7 using windows activation service (WAS), but this is not supported in IIS6.

This is quite an involved topic,  some links to get you started:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f0876bb1-55b0-4a3a-8205-51c7445e2c3b
[http://www.devx.com/VistaSpecialReport/Article/33831](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372935/wcf-and-msmq)

.. and of course the obligatory Stack Overflow reference

[Using Windows Services to process MSMQ messages via WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372935/wcf-and-msmq)